# How to put digits of a long long int into a long long int array

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, gcc, int

ok so I am trying to implement Client - server program (socket programming).

My client send a long long int embedded in a string like this:

```
char copy[10];
sprintf(send_data,"%s","Pre=");

for(i=0;i<7;i++){
    sprintf(copy,"%lld",premaster[i]);
    strcat(send_data,copy);
}

printf("\nSending CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE message\n");
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
```

SO send_data looks like `Pre=278262617263`

Now on the server side thus is what it looks like:

```
long long int preMaster;
long long int pre[100]={0};

numBytes = recv(clntSock,inMsg,1024,0); 
inMsg[numBytes] = '\0';

sscanf(inMsg, "Pre=%lld", &preMaster);
```

now I want to convert this preMaster into the element of pre array. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: BTW: Your `copy[10]` is too small.  An easy portable buffer size is `copy[sizeof(long long)*3 + 3]`.

Comment: thanks i implemented that into my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this, because you are sending ambiguous information: `Pre=278262617263` could mean any of the following:

- An array of one number `278262617263`
- An array of two numbers `27826261726` and `3`
- An array of two numbers `2782626172` and `63`
- An array of two numbers `278262617` and `263`
- ... more of the same
- An array of three numbers `2782626172`, `6` and `3`
- ... I think you got the idea

Fixing this requires fixing the sender first: make sure that you separate your numbers with a delimiter, and optionally send the number of items in the array to avoid dynamic re-allocation - for example,

```
Pre=5:27,826,26,17,263
```

is no longer ambiguous: it says that you are sending 5 items, and these items are delimited.